# Some DLL files are EMPTY in QT5.11.2 with mingw53_32

Tags: qt

Some dll files are empty just after I install the `QT5.11.2` with `mingw53_32`. Such as `Qt5Widgets.dll`, `Qt5Xml.dll`, `Qt5Widgetsd.dll` and so on.
Because of this my program can not run.

Any help please!

Comment: Check your antivirus. Download the binary package again and retry the install. if that does not work report a bug to the site you downloaded the binaries from. An additional option is to build Qt yourself.

Comment: OK, I'll try it, thank you ^_^